# cell.detailTextLabel.text is NULL

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell-formatting

I do not understand why my `cell.detailTextLabel.text` is null.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyId];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    /*[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellTest2" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = mealPlanCell;*/
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //self.mealPlanCell = nil;
}

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test";
```

It will let me set the `cell.textLabel.text` to a value but not the detail one.

Comment: That bit of code looks fine to me. There must be something else going wrong somewhere. Why do you think cell.detailTextLabel.text is null? How are you debugging this? What is your NSLog statement?

Comment: I have an nslog printing the detailTextLabel.text also I am not seeing anything on the screen in the cell for the detailLabel

Comment: It is not getting into the cell==nil if statement maybe because I am reusing the table and the first cell initially is not empty?

Comment: Agreed, cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test"; works perfectly, and so does the rest actually.

Comment: else{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

This is what is the other part of the code and I think that is preventing it from redefining the cell because when I walk through the code I go into this nil but when I reload the table with new values it will not go into the above if(cell == nil)

Comment: I found a work around. What you have to do is have the cell be formatted the same way for both of the cells because if not it will not restyle the cell. So in order for the detail not to show up for one and for it to show up for the other. You have to put an empty string in the cells that you dont want a detail and other wise add a detail to the ones you want and if the detail is an empty string it is like it is not there at all. Kind of a weird thing but it works that way. Thank you all for the input it helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason if you leave

```
if(cell == nil){...}
```

around the cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]...

then the cells will not re render and thus will not update the style and or details so if you remove the if() then this will allow you to re render each cell in the table view if you are changing style back and forth. This is not a good thing to remove though if you think about it cause then it is going to low the tables "speed" which probably wont be noticeable but it is something to consider looking into as a possible issue. This is not what I did to solve the problem personally cause I choose to take a different approach but it is something that worked when I tried.

Comment: Use a different reuse identifier for each type of cell. Then you get the benefits of reuse and the flexibility of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem:  [UITableViewCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485682/uitableviewcell-initwithstyleuitableviewcellstylesubtitle-is-not-working)

For those that search and find this question... and have same problem as me, where you are using a prototype cell and the style is not defined correctly in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If your rowHeight is not tall enough, the cell.detailTextLabel.text won't be visible even if the cell.textLabel.text is visible.  A rowHeight of 22 seems to be the minimum with the default font.