# UITableViewCell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle is not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having an issue in trying to display info in a cell, one on the left and one on the right.  I'm aware using `initWithStyle` with `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.  I use this but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is some sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)ltableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Account Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)  {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
    }

    Accounts *account = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = account.name;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Price";

    return cell;
}
```

I can display cell.textLabel.text just fine, however I cannot get the simple "Price" to be displayed.  I've tried different things, such as setting the font size of `cell.detailTextLabel`.

I've also tried `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` as some had suggested in older posts.
Threw NSLog after setting to "Price", shows cell.detailTextLabel as null.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:  I found this:  [cell.detailTextLabel.text is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792129/cell-detailtextlabel-text-is-null)

If I remove `if (cell == nil)` it works... 
That check should be in place, so how do you make it work when using the different styles?

Comment: Are you using that `CellIdentifier` anywhere else? Maybe you're actually dequeueing cells.

Comment: Either way, have you stepped through with the debugger to see what `cell` points to at each line?

Comment: Nope, CellIdentifier is not used elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't mean for this to become a how to use XCode... I'm very new to this and haven't used breakpoints and debugger.  Just figured out how to do it.  So, are you saying I should be looking at the value of what cell is at each breakpoint?  If so, I set some breakpoints throughout.  The style doesn't get set because it doesn't enter the if (cell == nil).  Each breakpoint shows cell the same value, for this run 0X06aa3140

Comment: Try changing `CellIdentifier` to something else, like "uniqueString".

Comment: Changed it as suggested, but same result.

Comment: Ah yes, I am using storyboards and it is also a prototype cell.  It is defined with custom style.

Comment: @jrturton:  good point.  They are prototype cells, but defind as custom.  ... or are you suggesting that it should be defined as subtitle?

Comment: @jrturton... I knew you were being... subtle... tried it and worked.  Also tried right detail.  Working as I wanted, thanks!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using storyboards and prototype cells, a cell is *always* returned from the dequeue method (assuming a prototype with that identifier exists). This means you never get into the `(cell == nil)` block.

In your case the prototype cell is not defined in the storyboard with the subtitle style, so a subtitled cell is never used, and the detail text label does not exist. Change the prototype in the storyboard to have the subtitle style.

Comment: Breakpoints clearly showed that I did NOT get into the if (cell == nil), as I state above.  Exactly as you said.  Changing the prototype cell style to subtitle worked!

Comment: @jrturton, how do this all in code? I did't use storyboard or nib.

Comment: @scorpiozj if you register a cell class with a reuse identifier in viewDidLoad, then this cell will be created automatically in the same way as if you'd registered a prototype in the storyboard. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @jrturton,yes. I register the UITableViewCell class in viewDidLoad and in the delegate method I find the cell != nil when I dequeue it.

Comment: I don't use storyboard, but the cell dequeued whose detailLabel is null.``UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
        // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all your code just once you try these lines only and check this will work or not.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
 }


   cell.textLabel.text=[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Price";


   return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem: in your method name, the `UITableView` variable is named `ltableView`, not `tableView`. Change it to `tableView`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to hand type this on my work machine.  That is a typo here, but not in the actual code.  I have to errors or crashes when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.detailTextLable.text` should be `cell.detailTextLabel.text`. It looks like a simple mis-spelling of label.

Comment: Sorry, I hand typed this out and not copied/pasted... fixed.  I have no errors and runs without crashing.  The "Price" will not display.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers mentioned here are really a workaround i.e. using storyboard.
Here is a way to do it only in code.

Basically instead of registering the identifier for the cell in viewDidLoad do it only once in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. Also reset cell registered in viewDidLoad  __sCellRegistered = 0;

```
    static int _sCellRegistered = 0;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;


if (__sCellRegistered == 0) {
    __sCellRegistered = 1;
    NSLog(@"register cell");

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
};

if (!cell) {
    NSLog(@"dequeue");

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```