# UITableView not showing detailText

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Text and image are showing properly, but detailText isnt.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CooperCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"subtitle";

    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

    return cell;
}
```

I set the right cell style, what else?

Comment: What have you tried? I tried googling the issue... multiple Q&A's with exactly the same question popped up.

Comment: It actually was the same problem. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @4ndro1d does it returns any cell?

Comment: It was the problem that the `if (cell == nil)` is never called.

Comment: @4ndro1d i think numberOfRowsInSection is not returning any values

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 2;
}

Answer (score 2):

First question, are you using storyboard? If so, are you using a prototype cell? If this is the case, then you are probably using the wrong style for the prototype.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485682/uitableviewcell-initwithstyleuitableviewcellstylesubtitle-is-not-working)  for futher explaination

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have to set the style in storyboard (or xib) as well, the condition if (cell == nil) will return true only id dequeueReusable fails. And dequeueReusable it's initialising the cell form nib/xib.