# UITableViewCell subtitle not appearing on load

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with cells where the subtitle only appears after something has been searched. This is the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test2";
    }
    else{
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = self.results[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"test1";

    }

    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: ArtOfWarfare's answer was correct. it was a problem in the storyboard. See image below:

[image]

Comment: so... `detailTextLabel.text` doesn't show anything until you _search_ for something.hm... what about `textLabel.text` before searching?

Comment: it's there, it looks just like when I used `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`

Comment: maybe this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10500210/2857130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that you have two separate tables... I would suggest that your problem lies within the differences in how the tables have been configured, possibly in your Storyboard.

Do you, perchance, have one of them set with a prototype with an identifier of "Cell" but a style that isn't UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle? That would make it so that your cell creation method isn't called in one, but only in the other.